# Illusion of control hardwired in brain?

Tags: personality, cognitive-neuroscience

Are there any research materials which deal with: need for control, illusion of control and neuroscience.

It will be very interesting to see if those illusions and needs could be linked to mental disorders like hypochondria, narcissistic personality disorder, psychosis etc., in an S-O-R scientific paradigm.

Comment: Stimulus-Organism-Response?

Comment: @JakeWestfall Thanks, I guess it doesn't need clarification.  I'll delete my comment.

Comment: Stimulus-Organism-Response [processes inside the organism are considered, here need for control etc.] vs. Stimulus-(black box)-Response [only input and output are considered]

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "need for control" and "illusion of control"? Specifically, it would be very helpful if you could find the terms for these things in research, even if they don't relate to neuroscience.